# how to custom error page from response 403 from .htaccess

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5.3

I protect .env file using .htaccess file, with this script :

```
<Files .env>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

if I access this file with url

```
https://myapp.mydomain.com/.env
```

I get this page error :
Forbidden

```
You don't have permission to access /.env on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

how to custom this page error ?

I try to override App\Exceptions\Handler.php like this :

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if($e instanceof HttpException && $e->getStatusCode() == 403){
        return abort(403,'Access Denied');
        }   
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

but no results

Comment: You should change your webroot to `public`. It is not safe to have the root of Laravel as your webroot.

Comment: sorry if I dont know, how to change my webroot to public, I locate my app to a subdomain (https://myapp.mydomain.com), and I can write to public_html/myapp only, how to resolve this

Comment: https://github.com/petehouston/laravel-deploy-on-shared-hosting

Comment: is this the same way as deploy on subdomain ?

Comment: Yes it is the same

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom error pages in Laravel by adding the appropriately named blade to the folder `resources/views/errors/` so for a custom `403` add the file `403.blade.php` to the above mentioned folder. Inside the blade you can use (from documentation) `$exception`, `dd($exception)` to get the handle of the message (more than likley `->getMessage()`)

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors#custom-http-error-pages)